# Custom Shipment Generation in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

down vote favorite

I am working on magento community version , I want to create shipment from backend in magento.

I had already done with custom quote sample and checkout method , I am not getting the solution which method I have to override to generate shipment from our custom API module.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a shipment programmatically you can do something like this:

```
/*
 * $itemsQty is an array where the key is the item id you want to ship
 * and the value is the quantity to ship for that item
 * $itemsQty = array($item->getId() => $item->getQtyOrdered());
 */
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment($itemsQty);
$shipment->register();
//$comment for the shipment, string
$shipment->addComment($comment);
$shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($shipment)
    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
    ->save();

$shipment->sendEmail();
$shipment->setEmailSent(true);
```

You can also save the tracking urls like this:

```
foreach ($trackingUrls as $trackingUrl) {
    Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
        ->setShipment($shipment)
        ->setData('title', 'SOME TITLE')
        ->setData('number', $trackingUrl)
        ->setData('carrier_code', 'CARRIER CODE')
        ->setData('order_id', $this->_order->getId())
        ->save();
}
```

Comment: We have created custom plug in in that we are already creating quote sample and now we want to create shipment ?

Comment: Ya but where we can create method for custom shipment generation and

Comment: As we are already done with shipping quote generation but we want to create custom shipment generation ,so how it will work and where it will put the out shipment method...

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you want or need.